# Syntactic and semantic rules

Tags: syntax, theory, semantics

There was a task on my exam, with a set of questions, where I had to pick the right answer among two statements. I didn't know which one to pick with these two:

```
Syntactic rules can be used to check semantic rules. 
Semantic rules can be used to check syntactic rules.
```

I know the definitions of the above terms (explained in layman's terms):

```
Syntactic rules:how we write something (an expression, for example) in a program
Semantic rules:what does that expression mean. Semantics is comprised of:
          *type-checking (ensuring the result has the right type) 
          *evaluation (evaluating the expression).
```

Can someone help me with the explanation? Which one would be correct?

Comment: The first one is false ("Syntactic rules can be used to check semantic rules.") - code can be syntactically correct, but [semantically meaningless](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209979/are-semantics-and-syntax-the-same) and [here](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=81) .