# Address of std::vector itself stable?

Tags: c++, vector

If I take the address of a `std::vector`, and it reallocates after inserting elements, can I assume its address does not change?

Thanks.

Comment: The address of the vector won't change.The address of the individual elements, not so much.

Comment: The address of a specific object never changes!

Comment: @NeilKirk Except for the specific objects in the vector, or any other container for that matter...

Comment: @Aggieboy No, those would be different objects.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, in C++ you can safely assume that. However, the address of the first element `&x[0]` *can* change, those addresses are not the same. **Edit:** the same is true for addresses of other elements, of course.

---

By the way, whether or not the address of the first element is likely to remain more or less stable depends on [whether or not the growth factor of the array is less than the golden ratio](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/docs/FBVector.md#memory-handling), which is a really cool fact to know IMO.

Comment: _" the address of the first element `&x[0]` can change"_ What about `&x[5]`? Wouldn't this change (invalidate because of reallocation)  too?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I assume OP is smart enough to get it by implication

Comment: The real answer is just a tick broader. But nevermind, you caught the case.

Answer (score 3):

> If I take the address of a `std::vector`, and it reallocates after inserting elements, can I assume its address does not change?

You can actually **always** assume that the address of a certain variable doesn't change, due to calling any behavior of it (that's not possible, since the language syntax prevents it. You cannot simply replace `this` with an arbitrary value).

*Reallocation* is a behavior of `std::vector`, that applies to it's underlying data structures (namely [`std::vector::data()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data)), and pointers taken from these overloads are unstable regarding this behavior and may change (same for any other addresses with offsets as taken e.g. from `ptr = &myVector[5];`).

Comment: "that's not possible, since the language syntax prevents it" - That's not true, there are GC libraries for C++ that don't require special smart pointer classes or syntax additions, and in general you can't guarantee something like this with syntax alone. I don't know if the one I'm linking to is doing reallocation or just mark-and-sweep, but in principle nothing is stopping GC from preempting the program and then walking its stack changing pointer values, it's all about implementation and maybe getting the complier to cooperate. http://www.hboehm.info/gc/simple_example.html

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko I don't actually see how this would be able to replace a `this` pointer arbitrarily with `nullptr` or another instance (but just skimmed now). Anyway if these special cases are relevant for the OP is arguable.

Comment: My point is C++ syntax doesn't guarantee things about values of variables, such guarantees inherently deal with the language's semantics.

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko My point is, that anything taken as address by the compiler at compile time like `MyClass a; MyClass aPtr =  &a;` won't ever change at runtime. You can try to bend around that, as much as you like, it's not possible, and also changing `this` from inside `MyClass` isn't possible.

Comment: Do you understand the [difference between syntax and semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209979/are-semantics-and-syntax-the-same)?

Comment: What you're saying is essentially that `&a` is an r-value, and thus it cannot be changed e.g. by assignment. That's true - and it's semantic, not syntactic property of `a`, syntax doesn't deal with values at all!

Comment: @AlexeiAverchenko _"Do you understand the difference between syntax and semantics?"_ Usually, yes I do. Maybe it's just not clear for me what's making the difference with your samples? _"but in principle nothing is stopping GC from preempting the program and then walking its stack changing pointer values,"_ I've got serious doubts about this (and even, if it's worth it). Usually address values obtained at compile time could be assumed not to change at run time. Did I miss something actually (by means of c++ standard guarantees)?

Comment: Yes, the GC was a bad example, I agree. What I was trying to point out is that syntax cannot prevent any behavior, because it doesn't deal with behavior at all

Comment: Again, forget GC, it's your claim that the *syntax* forbids this that's wrong.

Comment: @Puppy, actually, pointer values of local variables cannot be changed at all, even by the user, they're r-values. I agree that GC was a bad example.